# Spark Streaming : Driver refused to start receiver

Tags: spark-streaming

My streaming job has multiple custom receivers (10+) with checkpoint enabled.
When I start a job, I saw several receivers keeps restarting with the following error

[Executor task launch worker-1] receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopping receiver with message: Registered unsuccessfully because Driver refused to start receiver 3:

I searched and found a tip from http://scala4fun.tumblr.com/post/113172936582/how-to-spread-receivers-over-worker-hosts-in-spark. The idea is to delay the scheduler until enough number of executors are up.

It works when I start a job from a clean state. However, when I restart a job using a previous checkpoint, I am hitting the same issue. Many receivers keep restarting.

It looks like the trick didn't work when a checkpoint is used.
I am using the following function to create a StreamingContext, and the delay is done inside of fucntionToCreateContext

`val ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDir, functionToCreateContext)`

How can I start all the receivers when the job restarts with checkpoints?